# Remove duplicates in a list and check whether it's the same as another list

Tags: python, list

I am tasked to implement 'remove_extra(lst)' such that it takes in a list and returns the same list with all repeated occurances removed. Note: The order of elements in the returned list does not matter.
Hint: You can use sort or any other python list functions to make your life easier.

And I am given:

```
lst1 = [1, 5, 1, 1, 3]
lst2 = [2, 2, 2, 1, 5, 4, 4]
result1 = remove_extra(lst1)
result2 = remove_extra(lst2)
```

When the following expression is executed:

```
(result1 is lst1)
(result2 is lst2)
```

I should get True for both expressions but my output is False.
Please help me check my code:

```
def remove_extra(lst):
    new_lst = []
    for i in lst:
        if i not in new_lst:
        new_lst.append(i)

    return new_lst
```

Comment: Just convert the list to a `set`, which will remove duplicates.

Comment: `is` operator should not be used for comparing values

Comment: @thefourtheye: it looks like the OP wants to alter `lst1` *in place*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to alter `lst` in-place, assign to the full slice; use `set()` to produce a sequence of unique values instead of your loop:

```
def remove_extra(lst):
    lst[:] = set(lst)
    return lst
```

Assigning to a slice replaces the *elements* in the list, instead of rebinding the name `lst`. For the identity slice (from first to last element) that means we are replacing all elements with whatever elements are contained in the sequence on the right-hand-side of the assignment. `lst[:] = set(lst)` replaces all elements in `lst` with the elements in the *set* of the same list.

It is better not to return the same list object for in-place operations, however. There is little point, the original list has already been altered; Python built-in types always return `None` instead when a mutable object has been altered directly.

Demo:

```
>>> lst1 = [1, 5, 1, 1, 3]
>>> def remove_extra(lst):
...     lst[:] = set(lst)
...     return lst
... 
>>> lst1 = [1, 5, 1, 1, 3]
>>> result1 = remove_extra(lst1)
>>> result1 is lst1
True
>>> lst1
[1, 3, 5]
>>> lst2 = [2, 2, 2, 1, 5, 4, 4]
>>> result2 = remove_extra(lst2)
>>> result2 is lst2
True
```

Comment: @user3397867: I added a demonstration.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) but can explain to me how this works? why is it lst[:]?

Comment: @user3397867: `lst[:] = ....` assigns to the *indices* of the list; the slice with no start and end values defaults from the first to the last element, replacing all those elements with whatever elements are contained in the sequence on the right of the `=` sign.

Answer (score 0):

I would normally go with a `list(set(...))` implementation, but just for fun, here's a different way:

```
L = [2, 2, 2, 1, 5, 4, 4]
L.sort()
i = 0
while i<len(L)-1:
    print("j:", j)
    while L[i]==L[j] and j<len(L):
        L.pop(j)
    i += 1
```